# launch4j - Multiple jre version

Tags: java, launch4j

I would like to set the JRE preference `<minVersion>` specific to a Java version.

Something that look like that:

```
<jre>
  <minVersion>1.7.0_80</minVersion>
  <minVersion>1.8.0_74</minVersion>
 </jre>
```

The purpose is to ensure JRE for 7 will be min u80 and for 8 will u74.

Does anybody have tips for doing this.